# How to specify the number of bytes to send when using Socket.SendToAsync()?

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-4.0, udp, system.net

I have ported my UDP based protocol implementation from using the Socket.BeginXXX methods to the Socket.XXXAsync methods as they take the [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs(v=vs.100).aspx) class which has Buffer, Offset and Count properties so a single large buffer can be segmented and used for each operation.

Unfortunately I have just found out setting:

```
mySocketAsyncEventArgs.SendPacketsSendSize
```

Is not used when sending datagrams using:

```
mySocket.SendToAsync(mySocketAsyncEventArgs);
```

Instead the whole segment in SocketAsyncEventArgs.Buffer from Offset for Count bytes is sent! And I cannot use Socket.SendPacketsElements because that is only for connected Sockets!

Often I will only have a few bytes to send, but sometimes a thousand.. If the whole point of these overloads was to increase efficiency - they are not helping!

Please tell me there is way to specify the number of bytes to send in SocketAsyncEventArgs.Buffer on each operation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SetBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549836(v=vs.100).aspx) overload where you do not have to pass a byte[] buffer - just adjust the existing index and count to be used - then after the operation set count back to it's original value:

```
mySocketAsyncEventArgs.SetBuffer(mySocketAsyncEventArgs.Offset, numOfBytesWritten);
mySocket.SendToAsync(mySocketAsyncEventArgs);
...
mySocketAsyncEventArgs.SetBuffer(mySocketAsyncEventArgs.Offset, originalBufferSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

UDP Protocol will always send all data in one packet. you need to use TCP if you want to sent package sized that is not based on data.

Comment: I know UDP sends everything in one datagram but you can still decide the size of the datagram, e.g. if you use BeginSendTo(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginsendto(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `SendPacketsSendSize` to 0xFFFFFFFF and using `SendPacketsElement.EndOfPacket`?. It sounds promising in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.sendpacketssendsize.aspx

Comment: Ahh but that is only used if you are using SendPacketsElements which you then have to send using SendPacketsAsync which "Although intended for connection-oriented protocols, the SendPacketsAsync method also works for connectionless protocols, provided that you first call the BeginConnect, Connect, or ConnectAsync method to establish a default remote host." But I could have many remote hosts and I want to use a single Socket to send to them from..